# Помогите разобраться с массивом

Tags: javascript

Вопрос по сути мего примитивный, но он все же кладет меня на лопатки.
Есть массив, в нем айтемы подмассивы и строки, т.е. первый массив, следующий уже строка, потом опять массив и потом строки, скажем три подряд. Как объединить подмассив со стороками, скажем первый подмассив со строкой до айтема с новым подмассивом. И так по аналогии.

```js
  const arr = [['0'],'строка',['1'],'строка1', 'строка2']
```

Comment: для удобства восприятия вы бы кроме исходного массива привели бы еще и итоговый массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так и объединить. обходите массив, если элемент - массив, то его пихаете в конец. Если не массив, то к последнему добавляете

```js
const arr = [['0'],'строка',['1'],'строка1', 'строка2', [2], 'a','b','c'];

let result = arr.reduce(function(acc, v){
     if(Array.isArray(v)){
         acc.push(v);         } 
     else {
        acc[acc.length-1].push(v)
     }
     return acc;
  }, []);
  
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: Первая часть кода у меня была схожа как и у вас, на второе уже не хватило логики))Спасибо Вам огромное, за оказанную помощь, Вы мне очень помогли!!!